# JDBC MySQL retrieve Error Message Details

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Provoking Error 1452 in the mysql client produces following message:

```
mysql> INSERT INTO demo VALUES(1,3);
ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`test`.`demo`, CONSTRAINT `ContDemo` FOREIGN KEY (`fkpk`) REFERENCES `parentdemo` (`fkpk`))
```

I can't find a way to get the same message details in my JDBC implementation.
When I catch an SQLException it only contains the first part:

```
ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
```

How can I retrieve the constraint details of this error message in Java with JDBC?

```
(`test`.`demo`, CONSTRAINT `ContDemo` FOREIGN KEY (`fkpk`) REFERENCES `parentdemo` (`fkpk`))
```

Comment: Try getting the warnings (`stmt.getWarnings();`) as well. In any case this is highly dependent on the specific JDBC driver and version of it that you are using.

Comment: There are no Warnings, but I'm able to query `SHOW WARNINGS`. The ResultSet contains only the short Error message, not the details.

Comment: @Marvin, in jdbc, are you calling any stored proc or it just simple `insert` stmt?

Comment: @AshishPatil I'm using PreparedStatement to build my `insert` stmt.

Comment: @Marvin - I think `exception.getNextException().getMessage()` this may be helpful because `getNextException()` is retrieving vendor specific excpetion

Comment: @AshishPatil I tried your suggestion but my SQLException does not contain another Exception. `getNextException()` returns NULL

Answer (score -1):

Usually, when you catch the SQLException, the SQLException contains the Message/Error. You can retrieve them by using the SQLException object and print some of the several methods like SQLException.getMessage().

[image: Here you can see some of methods you can use to retrieve the Errormessage]

Comment: `SQLException.getMessage()` only contains "Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails"

Comment: Use the getStackTrace().toString() method

Comment: The Exception does not contain the MySQL Error Details I'm looking for.